# Hypothesis testing of categorical variable

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, categorical-data, survey, likert

I have extracted data from a questionnaire about factors influencing employability of young graduates. The questionnaire was answered by students in my class, so I extracted their age, major, and their degree of agreement with a bunch of statements I made. After importing data from the excel data sheet to R, I went through codification (converting the degrees of agreement to likert scale), and now I want to test some hypotheses.

So in the data frame of answers, we have these members representing the degree of agreement with each proposition between the quotes:

X1 = "The lack of professional experience is the main obstacle to the employment of young graduates."

X2 = "Young graduates are more likely to face unemployment, precariousness, and discrimination in the job market."

X3 = "The job market is constantly evolving, with the emergence of new jobs and the disappearance of others."

X4 = "Young graduates must be able to adapt to these changes and develop the skills necessary to meet the needs of the job market."

X5 = "Changes in demographics will have a significant impact on the job market."

Y1 = "Soft skills are essential for the professional integration of young graduates."

Y2 = "Soft skills include communication, collaboration, problem-solving, critical thinking, adaptability, and resilience."

Y3 = "Young graduates with soft skills are more likely to be successful in their work and career."

Y4 = "Employers are looking for employees who can work in a team, solve problems, and adapt to change."

Y5 = "Soft skills can be developed and improved over time."

Z1 = "The professional integration of young graduates is a major challenge in Morocco."

Z2 = "Factors favorable to the integration of young graduates include economic growth, improved education levels, and the implementation of public policies."

Z3 = "Factors unfavorable to the integration of young graduates include high unemployment, increased competition, and a lack of suitable training."

Z4 = "The integration of young graduates is possible for those who are well-prepared and have the necessary skills."

Z5 = "High competition and the mismatch between education and employment are specific challenges to the integration of young graduates in Morocco."

And the hypothesis I'm trying to test are the following:

H1: Recognizing the importance of soft skills in the context of professional integration is a significant perception.

H2: High competition and the mismatch between education and employment are challenges to the integration of young graduates.

H3: Professional experience represents a significant obstacle to access to employment.

My question is that meanwhile I don't have data set of the dichotomous variable "can be employed", what type of statistical model do I use to complete my work? what type of tests can I use to check the validity of my hypotheses?

Thank you all!

Comment: The typical use for tests of statistical hypotheses is to support inferences from samples towards populations within a statistical model, and those help reasonable extrapolation from the statistical inferences to inferences regarding the real world. Given that the dataset comes from a special class of people (those enrolled in your course at your university in the year in question) I do not think that there is a population outside of that group of people for inferences to be reliably extrapolated to. In other words, I question whether your 'sample' is a valid sample for testing hypotheses.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, you only have students' self-reports about what they *think* about different work life themes, so you can't really say anything about anyone's "employability" or access to employment based on your data (I don't understand your H1 - what does "significant perception" mean here?).

You will have to revise your hypotheses to reflect the nature of your data; e.g. you can form hypotheses about how different beliefs about work life are related to each other, or about how students with different majors differ in terms of their work life beliefs. Existing literature investigating similar themes (i.e. work life beliefs) will help you. Statistical models will not help you at this stage before you revise your hypotheses and clarify what you can do with your data.

Are the questions from some established survey? Are they supposed to measure some underlying attitude constructs? What is the rationale behind these questions exactly?

(Many of the questions are rather complex which may cause additional problems, such as that different respondents understand them differently)

Comment: +1, but from what I understand, OP doesn't say he wants to test anything about employability, he just mentions that the data comes from a survey originally about employability (i.e. it might be a secondary data analysis, without necessarily a relation to the reason why the data has been collected in the first place). But sure, the hypotheses mentioned at the end of the question should be made clearer and more specific. Also, the elephant in the room is that this is probably not a random sample of the population of interest

Comment: Yes this is probably true. I answered the way I did because OP says in the end that they don't have the variable "can be employed" and that that omission is a problem to testing their hypotheses, and because H3 implies that "access to employment" is the outcome variable. Hopefully OP clarifies what has been measured and what is the goal.